# Change Product Image on hover with image from gallery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

```
    <div  class="product_image">                                        
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <?php 
            $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
            $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); 
            $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 280, 300, true ); ?>

             <a rel="lightbox" href="<?php echo $img_url ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="" /></a>               
             <a class="cornerLink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Product Details <i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.product_image').hover(function(){
 $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});
```

Can someone please help, I need to make an on hover effect, when mouse is on product image, it changes to the image from product gallery.Have no clue how to get product gallery image.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You got to preserve the context of `this`, in your code `this` is pointing to `#largeImage`

```
$('.product_image').hover(function(){
 var newImg = $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large');
 $('#largeImage').attr('src',newImg);
});
```

Comment: $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{
 echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_catalog');

}  This is how i make gallery images appear, the problem is, I do not know how to make them appear on hover, the Jquery above is a example, no ideea how to make it work.

Comment: How to add, product gallery images.

Comment: My problem is that, i can not make the connection, i am new to this.